# Can't print a Full Block in Python 3.5 using a Raspberry pi and a Windows 10 Terminal

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

Command `print(u'\u2588')` works well in Python Online Compiler https://repl.it/languages/python3 but not in Raspberry pi through a windows 10 terminal using Putty. Following error appears:

```
>>> print('\u2588')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2588' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would appretiatte if someone could help...

Answer (score 0):

Problem got resolved with a fresh install of Raspbian Buster with Python 3.7.3 (previously I had Python 3.5).
This might have been the root cause...